# Sass Placeholders with @font-face

Tags: css, sass

Sass placeholders are hoisted to the top of compiled stylesheets. I'd like to harness this to force any `@font-face` declarations to the top of my stylesheets (before any other compiled placeholders).

But when I try to do this:

```
%font-face {
  font-family: 'FontName';
  src:url('fonts/FontName.eot');
  // other font files
}

@font-face {
  @extend %font-face;
}
```

Sass gives me this error: `Extend directives may only be used within rules.`

Does anyone know a way to make Sass placeholders work with `@font-face` or a workaround that will have the same result?

Comment: Placeholders do *not* go at the "top" of the compiled CSS.  They are positioned where they were defined relative to the other rules (which could place it at the very bottom!).

Comment: Added code that defines a placeholder after two mixins and `@extend`s placeholder after `@include`ing both mixins -- placeholder still shows up at top of compiled CSS

Comment: Again, they do not go at the top by default (see:  https://gist.github.com/cimmanon/4a61349a4539d86c1fa1).  Only `@import` statements are treated special and placed at the top of the compiled CSS.

Comment: For anyone else running into this issue, here is the code that was removed from my question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19214748/revisions

Answer (score 1):

You should use a mixin to handle the font-face import. It isn't going to work with a placeholder.

```
@include font-face;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding - a mixin won't do what I need because compiled mixins will always come after placeholders in the compiled stylesheet.

Comment: Shoot. That's unfortunate. Good question though, hope someone has a better answer so you can figure this out.